# why `echo HTTPS_PROXY=$HTTPS_PROXY` print an empty line when variable not set?

Tags: fish

shouldn't it be printing out `HTTPS_PROXY=` instead? (when $HTTPS_PROXY is not set)

I know I can work around using
`echo HTTPS_PROXY=(echo $HTTPS_PROXY)` or `echo HTTPS_PROXY="$HTTPS_PROXY"` , but I want to know why I need a work around in this case.

Answer (score 4):

In fish, all variables are lists. When you concatenate a string and a variable, what it does is combine every list element with the string.

So

```
set bar 1 2 3
echo foo$bar
```

prints "foo1 foo2 foo3".

Now, when you have an undefined variable (or an empty one, set like `set bar` without values), this combines nothing with the string, which ends up eliminating it.

You can think of it like any variable expansion being a brace expansion - `echo foo{1,2,3}` is the same as `echo foo$bar` with bar set like above.

In many cases, that is exactly what you want. Imagine $bar being a list of directories. To go over all files in them you could use

```
for file in $bar/*
```

and if $bar was empty (there was no directory), the entire loop would be skipped instead of e.g. showing all files in "/".

The obvious solution is to quote the variable if you want to supress this. Quoting turns the variable into always exactly one argument, even if it's empty or has multiple elements, so

```
echo foo"$bar"
```

prints "foo1 2 3" (as one argument).

This is documented at https://fishshell.com/docs/current/#combining-lists-cartesian-product.

Comment: `echo "HTTPS_PROXY=$HTTPS_PROXY"` is another work around